# What is "mainline"?

Tags: linux

I see the term in the context of Linux (kernel, usually - but maybe not always).

What does it mean? Even articles such as [this one](https://www.electronicproducts.com/Software/Development_Tools_and_Software/The_benefits_of_Mainline_Linux_and_the_mindset_of_upstream_development.aspx) and [the Linux kernel Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) seem to assume some knowledge of the concept without really defining it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux is open source, so there are *many* variations on it, i.e. *branches*. However,[Linus Torvalds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds) "is the creator and, historically, the principal developer of the Linux kernel... He also created the distributed version control system Git..." Therefore, the official repository at `git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git` contains the *mainline* Linux kernel, from which those branches diverge.

See [The Linux Kernel Archives](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/process/2.Process.html) to understand the development process.

Answer (score 0):

The original, unaltered release of (the kernel) (the app); see graf 2 of the section **Defining mainline** in the web page you cited, https://www.electronicproducts.com/Software/Development_Tools_and_Software/The_benefits_of_Mainline_Linux_and_the_mindset_of_upstream_development.aspx .

Of course, the wonderful thing about IT standards is *we have so many of them*, but that source seems authoritative.

Comment: Unaltered as in, without patches? So a release that is subsequently patched - that release without the patches would be a "mainline" release?